# Spark shuffle directory keeps growing in size

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How long are the shuffle files and data files stored on the block manager folder of the workers? (spark-a0ab5241-1b5e-4c73-93ed-f37bbc479591)

I have a spark streaming job with window duration of 2 hours and slide interval of 15 minutes.

When I execute the following command in my block manager path

```
find . -type f -cmin +150 -name "shuffle*" -exec ls {} \; //command to find the shuffle files older than 2 hours
```

I see a lot of files which means that they are not getting cleared which I was expecting that they should get cleared. There are even files from yesterday.

Subsequently, this size keeps on increasing and takes space on the disk.

Please suggest how to get rid of this and help on understanding this behaviour.